# Converting an array to an xhtml select list

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array given as:

```
$my_fontSizes = array("" => "100% Default", 
                      "150%" => "150% of default", 
                      "80%" => "80% of default" 
                );
```

When I turn this into a select list, how do I specify that the "value" of the option is what's on the left side of the => sign and the "text label" is what's on the right?

Example, here's what I'm using now, but the element on the right side of the => is being set as both the value and the label:

```
<select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
    <option<?php if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value='<?php echo $option; ?>'><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a slightly different form of foreach

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
```

Using this, you are able to grab both the key (left side) and the value (right side) for each option.

Comment: Thanks Tau_Zero, I appreciate your quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't mix your PHP and XHTML like that. It's messy and hard to maintain.

Second, note that you're printing `$option` as both the name and the value. Here's what I would do:

```
$my_fontSizes = array(
                    ""     => "100% Default", 
                    "150%" => "150% of default", 
                    "80%"  => "80% of default");

$HTML = sprintf('<select name="%s" id="%s">', $Value['id'], $Value['id']);

foreach ($my_fontSizes as $Key => $Value)
{
    $Selected = ($OtherValue == $Value) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    $HTML .= sprintf('<option %s value="%s">%s</option>', $Selected, $Key, $Value);
}

$HTML .= '</select>';

echo $HTML;
```

Comment: Thanks Zach. I appreciate the explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a slightly different `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
```

So your code would be:

```
<select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $value $option) { ?>
    <option<?php if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value='<?php echo $value; ?>'><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a variable named $value and "100% Default" will need a value (like 0 OR null , just to fill the space) but your can loop through your array and get the value and option text like so:

```
<select>
<?php
foreach($my_fontSizes as $value => $key)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="<?=$value['id']?>" id="<?=$value['id']?>">
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $value=>$option) { ?>
    <option<?=(get_option( $value['id'] ) == $value ? ' selected="selected"' : '')?> value='<?=$value?>'><?=$option?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And a slightly more cleaned up markup (but the same answer as everyone else)

Answer (score 0):

You would use array_keys() and go through the keys to print the option values.